# VueJS Element и события

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

Всем привет. Изучаю vuejs. Использую библиотеку на его основе - [Element](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) Но есть проблема, с событиями. В компоненте FormBuilder есть событие form-builder-fields

```
this.$root.$emit('form-builder-fields', createElement, fields, fieldAttributes);
```

И есть компонент Image в котором я его ловлю

```
this.$root.$on('form-builder-fields', (createElement, fields, fieldAttributes) => {
        fields['image'] = () => {
            console.log('Image widget created successfully')
            return createElement('ElUpload', {
                props: {
                    action: '111222333',
                    onSuccess: this.successEvent(),
                    listType: 'picture-card',
                    fileList: []
                }
            }, [createElement('i', {
                attrs: {
                    class: 'el-icon-plus'
                },
            })])
        };
        return fields;
    });
```

Это два независимых компонента.
С помощью createElement в компоненте Image я создаю стандартный компонент с библиотеки Element, вот он [ElUpload](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/upload/src/index.vue). Проблема в том что событие onSuccess компонента ElUpload срабатывает когда происходит событие form-builder-fields. Т.е. код метода successEvent() выполняется сразу, не дожидаясь события onSuccess ну или onSuccess срабатывает сразу. Суть вопроса в том собственно, как это исправить ?

Comment: Вот тут у вас два лишних символа есть: `onSuccess: this.successEvent()`. Догадайтесь какие именно.

Comment: Какие ? Я просто не совсем понимаю к чему вы клоните, если вы о скобках, разве если я их уберу то это не превратиться в переменную, следовательно в ошибку, т.к. такой переменной нет. Если насчет синтаксиса, так ошибок никаких дебагер не выдает, вроде бы верно все...

Comment: А вы попробуйте

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, действительно сработало. Никогда бы сам не додумался. Правда событие два раза срабатывает, но это явно не в этом проблема. А вот за скобки никогда бы не подумал. Еще раз огромное Вам спасибо :)

Comment: Скобки - это не отличие переменной от функции, а вызов функции. Со скобками у вас не работало потому что вы вызывали функцию сразу вместо ее передачи.

Comment: Вот ведь, не даром говорят - век живи, век учись. Даже не знаю сколько бы еще просидел, если бы не Вы. Еще раз огромнейшее Вам спасибо :)

Comment: Оформите ответом

Comment: Лень. Все равно надо будет потом канонический ответ писать, а то ваш вопрос довольно часто попадается...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как куда-нибудь передать функцию // почему событие вызывается сразу же?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719926/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5)